# Why doesn't SML allow if-then without else?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, conditional-statements

In Standard ML, what was the reasoning behind having if-then-else as a single expression and not allowing only if-then without else clause?

Is it possible to write conditional statements in SML without the else clause?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Standard ML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_ML) programs are *expressions*, not *statements*.

> Standard ML is a functional programming language with some impure features. Programs written in Standard ML consist of expressions to be evaluated, as opposed to statements or commands [as found in C-like languages] ..

As such, because `if-then-else` is an *expression*, it must evaluate to a value. If the `else` was not required then the expression would effectively "have no value" if the condition failed - but by definition of an expression, it *must* have a value. Requiring an explicit `else` ensures that the expression will evaluate to value in both cases<sup>1</sup>.

Furthermore, the type from the `then` and `else` expressions *must* be unified - this will be the type of the entire `if-then-else` construct.

That is, `if-then-else` in SML is like the ternary (`?:`) operator in C-like languages, which also shares this "restriction". It is *not* equivalent `if`-*statements* whose branches are evaluated for *side effects only*.

---

<sup>1</sup> Not all functional-like languages require an explicit `then` expression and some will default to a particular value. However, this is just how it works in SML which makes sense because there need not be a "default value" for any particular type and the resulting types must be unified.

Comment: I think the "However, this is just how it works in SML" is basically what your answer boils down to. OCaml is just as functional as SML. But it allows you to omit the `else` clause.

Comment: Well, it's “that much less” functional than SML apparently.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't specific to Standard ML; many or most languages with if-then-else expressions require an else-expression. For example, in C-like languages (C, C++, C#, Java, D, Perl, JavaScript, PHP, etc.), the expression takes the form `cond ? expr_if_true : expr_if_false`; in Visual Basic the `Iif` function requires both an expression-if-true and an expression-if-false; and so on. (There are some languages, such as the Excel formula language, that do not require both values, and substitute a default for the else-expression, but SML is hardly exceptional in not doing so.)

> Is it possible to write conditional statements in SML without the else clause?

SML doesn't have any concept of "statements", let alone "conditional statements". It has *declarations*, but it doesn't make sense to declare something only conditionally (since type information is all determined at compile-time, whereas conditions of course can't be evaluated until run-time).

If you want to take a certain action when a condition is true, and take no action when the condition is false, you just need to use a conditional expression where only the then-expression has a side effect. For example:

```
val _ = if i > 30 then print "i is too big!" else ()
```

(where `print "Yay!"` and `()` are both expressions of type `unit`).

Comment: OCaml is a very close relative of SML, and OCaml's if-then-else expression is almost identical to SML's. But OCaml allows you not to have an `else` clause; it is equivalent to `else ()`. I think the answer is just, that's how SML does it.

Comment: @newacct: Sorry, I'm not sure what part of my answer you're objecting to. All I said is that SML is far from unique in requiring an `else` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you are saying, but if the "if" statement of your function returns false then the program doesn't know what to do. You probably just want the function to keep going if the expression is false....right?

If you want that to happen then you have make your "else" do something that just passes on to the rest of the function.

I actually don't know much about SML so i couldn't tell you how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Because otherwise, what would be the value of the expression if the `if` branch does not match? To not need the `else` branch would require a default value can be inferred. The only thing I see which could make sense, is to raise an exception. Could have been an option for the design of SML, but this was not and would not have been a lot relevant any way.

Whenever you feel there is no valid expression value on `else`, then just say something like this:

```
val x = 
   if condition then expression 
   else raise Domain;
```